# Updating Label inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, label

i have a label and button inside update panel, when i try to get the value from the label on the button click, i get the value from label, but when i try to set the value to the label, it does not happens, i checked for JavaScript error, but there wasn't any, does anyone have any guess what could be the reason. i am using dotnetnuke and here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSection6" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/images/edit.gif" ID="btnEditSectionStory6" runat="server" OnClick="Clicked" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here's the code

```
protected void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lbl.Text="Welcome";
}
```

Comment: I have added some additional C# code to my original answer. This should work 100% as I have tested it in my development environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add  the following code

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEditSectionStory6" />
</Triggers>
```

Just before your closing `</asp:UpdatePanel>`

So your code should look like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSection6" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/images/edit.gif" ID="btnEditSectionStory6" runat="server" OnClick="Clicked" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEditSectionStory6" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**ASP PostBackTrigger**

> Specifies a control and event that will cause a full page update (a
>   full page refresh). This tag can be used to force a full refresh when
>   a control would otherwise trigger partial rendering.

You can [read more](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) about [UpdatePanel's and Triggers here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers).

**C# (using the ImageClickEventArgs)**

```
    protected void Clicked(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Welcome";
    }
```

Comment: hi @Seany84 thanks for your reply, but this too seems not working, i added the trigger and also associated the control id, but still i am not getting the value inside the label

Comment: @Abbas Can you all of the ASPX and C# you have for that page.

Comment: @Abbas Please see the C# code I have added to my original response. Please pay attention to the type of EventArgs the ImageButton uses i.e. ImageClickEventArgs and not EventArgs.